# for_each pointer in a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

I'd like to initialize a vector of pointers in for_each() function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Cow{
        public:
                Cow(){ _age = rand()% 20; }
                int get_age() { return _age;}
        private:
                int _age;
};

void add_new(Cow* cowp)
{
        cowp = new Cow;
}

int main()
{
        srand(time(NULL));
        const int herd_size=10;
        vector<Cow*> herd(herd_size);
        for_each(herd.begin(), herd.end(),add_new);
        cout << "Age: " << herd[0]->get_age() << endl; // line 27
}
```

However, I get a runtime "Segmentation fault" error at line 27. The herd vector seems to be uninitizlized. Why?

Comment: Please `:set nonu` and label the lines in question with comments, so that we can copy-paste code and compile without mucking about.

Comment: @jdero "add_new" is the call back function on each element of the vector.

Comment: Please don't include the line numbers, it makes it very annoying for people to copy and paste. Just mark the necessary lines with a comment.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be herd[it] ?

Comment: Jim: no, I just want to print the first element

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function takes the pointers in by value, then reassigns those copies.  You need to take them in by reference in order to affect the pointers in the vector.

```
void add_new(Cow *& cowp)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
void add_new(Cow* cowp)
{
        cowp = new Cow;
}
```

You are only modifying the local version of your `Cow` pointer. Remember that a local variable is destroyed upon leaving its function, and here your pointer is passed as value !

You want to modify the pointers that reside inside your vector, so you need references :

```
void add_new(Cow *& cowp)
{
  cowp = new Cow;
}
```

That way, you are effectively modifying the original pointers that reside in your vector.

Answer (score 3):

For this [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) is a better match, as it's supposed to be used for generation of a sequence.

The other important change is that your function must take a *reference* to the pointer:

```
void add_new(Cow*& cowp)
```

---

Actually, you don't really need to use `std::for_each` or even `std::transform`, or use a separate creation functions, thanks to the new C++11 functionality:

```
for (auto& cow : herd)
    cow = new Cow;
```

And I would actually recommend you to *not* use pointers at all, so no other initialization would really be needed.

Comment: If we're switching algorithms, `generate` would probably be better than `transform`, since the new value is in no way dependent on the old value.